# Add slashes to date string containing only numbers

Tags: php, string, date, substring

I got this variable:

```
$payments['date'] = 21062013
```

The problem:

Its a date, so I want to add slashes to this string.

How I'm trying:

```
echo $paymentdate = substr($payments['date'],2)+/+substr($payments['date'],4)+/substr($payments['date'],8);
```

It's not working, can some one help?

my full code:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($SQL->query('SELECT id, form, email, value, data, date, compensated from payments where compensated="N"') as $payments)
{
 $i++;
 $paymentdate = substr($payments['date'], 0, 2)."/".substr($payments['date'], 2, 2)."/".substr($payments['date'], 2, 8);
 echo '<tr bgcolor="' . (is_int($i / 2) ? $config['site']['darkborder'] : $config['site']['lightborder']) . '">  
  <td>' . $payments['id'] . '</td>
  <td>' . $payments['form'] . '</td>
  <td>' . $payments['email'] . '</td>
  <td>' . $payments['value'] . '</td>
  <td>' . $paymentdate .'</td>
  <td>' . $payments['data'] . '</td>
  <td>' . $payments['compensated'] . '</td>
  <td>a</td>
 </tr>';
}
```

Comment: to join strings use `.` example: `echo $string1.function()."string".$another_variable;`

Comment: `echo $paymentdate = substr($payments['date'],2) . '/' .  substr($payments['date'],4) . '/' . substr($payments['date'],8);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you;

```
echo $paymentdate = substr($payments['date'], 0, 2)."/".substr($payments['date'], 2, 2)."/".substr($payments['date'], 4, 4);
```

Comment: I updated main post, its showing slash in wrong places to each line.

Comment: I tested with yours and the same problem :/

Comment: what does it show then, because if your string is `21062013`, this solution would output `21/06/2013`

Comment: First line 20/06/2013 Second line: 20// Third line: 20/06/2013 Fourth Line: 15//

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtotime()` function for changing the way that it can be displayed.

```
<?php echo date("m/d/y", strtotime("20130621")); ?>
```

Comment: The date is in the asked question is in `dmy` format.

Answer (score 1):

Please :

- Learn the [concatenation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).
- Read the documentation for [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

`substr($payments['date'], 0, 2) . '/' . substr($payments['date'], 2, 2) . '/' . substr($payments['date'], 4, 4);`

Comment: I updated main post, its showing slash in wrong places to each line.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertDate($date, $format = 1)
{
    $newDate = "";

   //Convert a string to an array
   $num = str_split($date);

   switch(format)
   {
     case 1:
        $newDate = $num[0].$num[1]."/".$num[2].$num[3]."/".$num[4].$num[5].$num[6]$num[7] ;
        Break;

        // .... 
   }

 return $newDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your data is coming from a MySQL database, it makes more sense to format your data before it hits PHP. I'll show how to convert your numbers into a `Y-m-d` date string, and how to create a `d/m/Y` date string using SQL: ([Demo](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/95848b837d254dda74c7ad4b912fe495/php/php81/8c9fdf1250c29f6a799312dfdb6c6ee9/))

```
SELECT id,
       STR_TO_DATE(`date`,'%d%m%Y') AS `Y-m-d_format`,
       DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`date`,'%d%m%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y') AS `d/m/Y_format`
FROM payments
```

---

Here are some viable PHP techniques for your `dmY` formatted string: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JdphY))

```
$payments['date'] = 21062013;
```

- Inject slashes at the 2nd and 4th positions:

  ```
  echo preg_replace('/\d\d\K/', '/', $payments['date'], 2);
  ```
- Parse as three separate strings then implode with slashes:

  ```
  echo implode('/', sscanf($payments['date'], '%2s%2s%4s'));
  ```
- Create a Datetime object, then output in the new format:

  ```
  echo DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', $payments['date'])->format('d/m/Y');
  ```

  equivalent to:

  ```
  echo date_create_from_format('dmY', $payments['date'])->format('d/m/Y');
  ```

Because your date string is in `dmY`, PHP's `strtotime()` cannot parse it correctly:

- ```
  // DO NOT USE echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($payments['date']));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date strings would always be fixed width in the format `mmddYYYY` you could use a regex replacement here:

```php
$sDate = "21062013";
$output = preg_replace("/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})$/", "$1/$2/$3", $sDate);
echo $output;  // 21/06/2013
```

For another more robust and general approach, we can do a rountrip conversion from string to date, then date back to string in the format desired:

```php
$sDate = "21062013";
$ymd = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', $sDate)->format('d/m/Y');
echo $ymd;  // 21/06/2013
```